# Recommended way to store and retrieve objects with inheritance

Tags: neo4j

What is the recommended way to store and retrieve objects that inherit properties from other objects in Neo4j?

Models look like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedA : Base
{
    public string DerivedAProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class DerivedB : Base
{
    public string DerivedBProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

We have lots of Derived Models. Our first solution was to create a Transaction for each Derived Type which includes the properties from Base as well. Problem: Whenever Base would change we would have to change all transactions for all derived types.

Next solution was to write a separate Transaction for Base which would store its properties into neo4j first. And then after determining which derived type, another transaction is created that stores the remaining properties from the derived type. This way the transaction number is doubled, but we have a clean separation that makes changes easier.

Retrieval is even harder. If we want to get all DerivedA types that are stored in Neo4j, we first have a transaction that retrieves the base properties. Then we determine the derived Type and follow up with a new transaction that retrieves the properties from the derived type. Now we have to mix the results from both transactions together in the correct way to get the full derivedA list with all properties inside.

Is there an easier / better way?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is broad, there is an alternative for inheritance. If that is your question, I think it's a valid one.

An alternative for inheritance is, (for example) the decorator pattern:

The core principle (taker from head-first design patterns):

> The key point of the decorator pattern is that it's an alternative to inheritance, with the same ability to alter and extend behavior at run time and without being tied to some base class with a specific version or other dependencies.

An example, from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879329/simplified-decorator-pattern-is-that-correct/46879442#46879442):

More about the subject on [wikipedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879329/simplified-decorator-pattern-is-that-correct/46879442#46879442)

I'll alter this to be more representative.

```
public interface IStudent //this would rather be called an IInformationDisplayer
{
     string DisplayInformation();
}

public class Student : IStudent
{
    public string Name, Grade, Age, etc... { get; set; }
    private IStudent _student = null;

    public Student() { }
    public Student(IStudent student) {  _student = student; }

    public string DisplayInformation()
    {
        return $"{_student?.DisplayInformation()}" + 
               $"{Name} - {Age} years old is in {Grade} grade";
    }
}

public class ScienceStudent : IStudent //it's still a decorator
{
    public string Labs { get; set; }
    private IStudent _student;
    public ScienceStudentDecorator(IStudent student)
    {
        _student = student;
    }

    public string DisplayInformation()
    {
        var info =  _student?.DisplayInformation();
        return $"{info}. Labse are {Labs}";
    }
}
```